# Python in C++ or C++ pure for file templates manipulation?

Tags: python, c++, file

(I don't know if I can post such a question here)

I have a problem for which I need a suggestion. I've a C++ code that derive several parameters (which are numbers basically). Such numbers have to be used to generate further code, of which I have templates, as very trivial example a template could look as something like:

```
#define PAR1 <PAR1>
#define PAR2 <PAR2>
//other parameters, function declaration, tables and so on...
```

In the example above ,  and all the possible others are derived by the C++ code mentioned above.

What would be, in your opinion, a good approach to achieve the parameter replacement?

I was thinking at two solutions, but I don't know which one would be the best:
1. I could write several python scripts (as many as I need) for string replacement for given parameters, such scripts has to be called in the C++ application once the parameters have been derived.
2. Reading the stream of the template file, look for the position of the parameters to be replaced and the replace it.

The first solution would require to call the pythons script from the C++ application and I don't know how to do that, I've been looking at some solution, and to be honest I don't know how simple it is.

The second solution is C++ file manipulation, which could be a bit of a pain in my specific case?

Since what I'm up to is the easiest way to achieve my goal which one would you suggest?

Thx

Update: I'm trying to be a bit more specific by posting a trivial example. A possible template, extremely minimal, could be the following:

```
//header_template.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <stdio.h>

#define A <A>
#define B <B>
#define C <C>

void func1();
void func2();
void func3();

#endif
```

The source file
    //src.c
    #include "header.h"

```
void func1() {
  int i, my_array1[A];
  for(i = 0; i < A; i++) {
     my_array1[i] = do_something(i);
  }
  //other processing;
}

void func2() {
  int i, j, my_matrix[A][B];
  for(i = 0; i < A; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j < B; j++) {
        my_matrix[i][j] = do_something_2(i,j);
     }
  }
}

void func3() {
  int i;
  int my_array[A + B + C];
  for(i = 0; i < A + B + C; i++) {
     my_array[i] = do_something_else(i);
  }
}
```

The parameters `A, B, C` are derived by some other processing operations prior the code generation, what I want to achieve is something like:

```
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 17
#define B 9
#define C 37

void func1();
void func2();
void func3();

#endif
```

My question is: doing text replacement using python is very easy, in C++ is not that easy. The processing of the parameters A,B and C is done by something implemented in C++, I need to extend such program for for such replacement, given the fact I've been using C++ so far is it better to develop small python programs and then call such scripts in the C++ program or is it better just to implement functions in C++ for the replacement?

The example I made can sound trivial, which is true, however the actual code I'm dealing with, and I'm posting larger of course so what I'm asking is what you would do in such a case.

Comment: The crap in <code><PAR1></code> for example could be replaced with the number <code>12348794684</code>

Comment: You have C code with stuff to be replaced here and there with other stuff. I basically have a parametric code, such parameters have to be derived elsewhere, once such parameters has been derived they've to be written in that file instead of <code><PAR1></code>, for example. Maybe such parameters specify array size or something else. I have sources with 30 parameters to be assigned as macro definitions for example. I don't understand what do you mean with "costum file".

Comment: You want something like [that](http://ideone.com/KaqG3Y) ? Or do you really want new file with code replaced (ala `configure.in`) (or some kind of `gcc -E` but without the include part).

Comment: something like gcc -E

Comment: Why should I include a <code>config.h</code>?

Comment: Don't I still have the replacement problem but just moved into a different file?

Comment: Done it, I don't think I can explain better than this. In the example I added for example I want to generate code that doesn't do dynamic allocation, somehow I compute the worst case parameters and I stick them into the C code.

Comment: This may be a case of the [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: So autoconf and other build system have template replacement. Which build system do you use ?

Comment: @rtmh I have a problem for I which I know how to solve in several ways (C++ or Python+C++), since I don't know how difficult could be to interface Python code with C++ I was asking which route would be better in your opinion.

Comment: @Jarod42 I suppose I could use autoconf

Comment: I'm not an expert in build systems, but I don't understand why such tools are related to what I have to do.

Comment: @user8469759 I certainly don't know, but I wonder if there is a better way to approach the program's structure that might avoid the need to generate c++ code for different configurations. I'm fairly inexperienced myself, so I merely seek to provide another (hopefully helpful) perspective.

Comment: That's not a degree of freedom, I have to generate code. There's no other way, it's a constraint.

Comment: @user8469759 as for calling python scripts, I stumbled upon [this](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) when trying to do the same (run python from c++), I hope it's helpful :)

Comment: @user8469759 Also, I have heard of [Template Metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming), which seems to intersect with this. (I really am not sure, becuase I lack experience with it, but who knows)

Comment: Just wanna tell you I really appreciate all of your effort, I understand it's a kind of "tricky" question (or twisted somehow).

Answer (score 1):

Although I am a Python enthusiast, I think for this one you should stay within C++ (since it seems you have already a significant amount of C++ code) and use a decent library like Boost. You could consider using Cython as a bridge, but my estimation is that it would be overkill.